# IndexError: list index out of range - Forward Substitution

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, range

I'm writing a function to perform forward substitution on a row-reduced matrix which has 1's along the diagonal. I don"t know why, but it keeps telling me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#128>", line 1, in <module>
    yvect=forwardSub(augL)
  File "C:\Users\Anna\Documents\Math400\Code\Assignment1.py", line 515, in  forwardSub
    for i in range(rs):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code.

```
def forwardSub(aug):
    cs=len(aug[0])-1
    rs=len(aug)-1
    sol=[0 for k in range(cs)]
    for i in range(rs):
        sol[i]=(aug[i][cs] - sum([aug[i][j]*sol[j] for
                                  j in range(0,cs)]))
    return(sol)
```

Can someone explain what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `sol` in terms of `cs`, but access it in terms of `rs`.